# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, model

I was creating one model file and trying to fetch the table data using this model.

Every time it's showing the error below:

> "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'laravel_student.students' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from
>   `students`)"

The controller file looks like to the following:

```
namespace project1\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use project1\Student;
use project1\Http\Requests;
class StudentController extends Controller
{


public function index() 
{

    $students = Student::all();
    return view('student_form',compact('students'));

}
}
```

Comment: Does the table "laravel_student.students" exist? Apparently not

Comment: thank you for reply.... i am upload database image

Comment: Check if the table really exists in your db first, ensure that you have already run the migration and let us know . I recommend you to use tinker with your command line, it's really useful.

Comment: thank's javipedrera for reply using "  $students = DB::table('student')->get(); " this line i was getting all table data but using model it's not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your `Student Model`

and add `$table`

```
class Student extends Model {
  protected $table = 'student';
}
```

Follow [Eloquent Defining Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models) for more details